# Passing two variables in a ForEach controller in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am running a ForEach controller in which I want the controller to run the service underneath it for changes in sets of latitudes and longitudes. example-

Input variable prefix: `latitude`

Output variable name: `Latitude`

I want to run the controller for changes in both "latitude" and "longitude". I tried doing this-

Input variable prefix:`latitude, longitude`

but it does not work. Is there any other way to pass two variables in ForEach controller?

Answer (score 17):

Unfortunately you cannot do it using ForEach Controller, but you can work it around using [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function combination.

For example you have 4 JMeter Variables:

```
latitude_1=40.7128° N
longitude_1=74.0059° W
latitude_2=32.0853° N
longitude_2=34.7818° E
```

And you want to iterate them both using ForEach Controller. In that case the relevant configuration would be:

- Input variable prefix: `latitude`
- Output variable name: anything meaningful, i.e. `current_latitude`

You can refer matching longitude value using the following expression:

```
${__V(longitude_${__counter(,)})}
```

Demo:

[image: Combine Variables]

See [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) for detailed explanation of where did the above expression come from.

Comment: Which element have you used for the fromular: ${__V(longitude_${__counter(,)})} ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem and google a lot to find the best possible solution but 
did not get success. I am sharing my work-around (and I am not saying it's a great solution ) -

1. Mention your Input variable name (ex - inputVar) as well as Output variable name (outputVar) on ForEach Controller

(lets say http://website.com/folder_A/folder_B/123_latitude/456_longitude) and you like to take care these two : latitue and longtitude

2. Use **regular expression extractor** :

Name of created variable :  inputVar

Expression : http://website.com/folder_A/folder_B/(.*)

Template : $1$

match No : -1  // (yes -1 , this will give you complete group)

3. Handle with regular expression (just search it out ) 
   so for above example : that would be -

http://website.com/folder_A/folder_B/${outputVar}

4. http://website.com/folder_A/folder_B/${outputVar}  URL will be able to print / give you latitue and longtitude in your response code