# jmeter ${__V(longitude_${__counter(,)})} use inside foreach controller

Tags: foreach, controller, jmeter, counter

I have referred this thread [Passing two variables in a ForEach controller in jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463960/passing-two-variables-in-a-foreach-controller-in-jmeter) and able to pass multiple variables into the foreach controller

In foreach controller I am using URL variable which works fine and iterate through all the results from previous response extraction. But when I use ${__V(longitude_${__counter(,)})} it doesn't reset to 0 and when I hot the 2nd iteration item it doesn't match. how Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Function [__counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) is by default global, to make it per user, set first argunent as TRUE.in your case:

```
 ${__V(longitude_${__counter(TRUE,)})}
```

> TRUE if you wish each simulated user's counter to be kept independent and separate from the other users.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I have in as Response Assertion  ---      <li class="product level6">
        
            ${__V(modelNumber_${__counter(TRUE,)})}
        
    </li>
</ol>   ---  This works fine for the 1st round but it doesn't reset to 0 for 2nd round - it just keeps goes on